# How to adapt Image size on tablet 10,1" MDPI

Tags: android, android-studio, tablet, multiscreen

My app uses a background (720x1280) in xhdpi. I created all the drawable folders to support the differents screen sizes (hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi...). For the phones, it works.

Note that I use a canvas, not an activity.

Now I want to run my app on a tablet in MDPI with this resolution 800x1280

According to what I read in the documentation, I have to put all drawables in the MDPI folder with the ratio of 50% (from xhdpi folder), right ?

But when I run my app on the tablet, the drawables are very small..

Do I have to create all drawables by adapting their size to the resolution of the tablet ? so with a background 800x1280 ?

Thank you

Gigi

Comment: Write your title to describe the issue you need help with.